# How can I return a called back function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I using Angular's `$http` to get questions, which expects a promise in return, either `success` or `error`:

```
Question.getQuestions().success(function (res) {
    ...
}).error(function (err) {});
```

In my method, I need to check if token is expired, if so, refresh, *then* make the request to `/questions` and return the promise. Otherwise, just make the request to `/questions` as usual:

```
getQuestions: function() {

   // this is called by refreshToken but not returning the $http promise
    var get = function() {
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: url + ver + '/questions',
            ...
        });
    };

    if (Auth.tokenIsExpired()) {
        return Auth.refreshToken(get);
    } else {
        return get();
    }
},
```

The refreshToken is another `$http` which relies on a promise, then calls the `get()` callback.

```
Auth {...

    refreshToken: function(callback) {
        ...
        _this.getAuth(OAuth).success(function (access_obj) {
            //set token
            callback();
        })...
```

Where getAuth is another `$http promise`:

```
    getAuth: function(params) {
            return $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: url + '/oauth/access_token',
                ...
            });
        },
```

All of these methods are called as expected, but am getting error:

`Cannot read property 'success' of undefined`

This is because `Auth.refreshToken(get)` is not returning the `/questions $http` call as it should. How can I return the promise from that back to the original `Question.getQuestions()`?

Comment: so what is `_this.getAuth`?

Comment: @zerkms see above edit

Comment: shouldn't you use then() instead of success(), and why don't you return _this.getAuth(...) and return callback();

Comment: `success` and `error` are not promise methods...and in fact are deprecated

Comment: @charlietfl right but isn't `$http` a promise object? So I'm returning that. It'd be helpful if you could explain why if Im returning `$http` promise, why it matters if I use `success` vs `then`

Comment: you need to return the callback in rereshToken. you're not sending the promise back in that chain.

Comment: Because using success and error are not part of the promise chain. Each `then()` returns to the next `then()` in chain and any error thrown in middle of chain is caught at end of chain

Comment: @charlietfl I'm wondering if instead of wrapping each $http request in return Auth.refreshToken().then(function () {, shouldn't I use $httpProvider.interceptors to intercept the requests before they go out, check if Auth needs to refresh the token, then it will move on to the $http request?

Comment: That would be practical

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a suggestion since your code looks over-complicated.

```
getQuestions: function() {   
    var get = $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: url + ver + '/questions',
        ...
    }); 
    if (Auth.tokenIsExpired()) {
        return Auth.refreshToken().then(function(){
         return get();
        });
    } else {
        return get();
    }
}

refreshToken: function() {
    return _this.getAuth(OAuth).then(function (access_obj) {
        //set token
    });
}
```

Basically refreshToken should refresh the token and return a promise for when its done. Then when you `GET` the questions you check if the token is expired, if it did then you call `refreshToken` and when its done (`.success()`/`.then()` is called you do the usual `GET`)

You can simplify this further and let `Auth` handle all of the token refreshing for you by moving the line `Auth.tokenIsExpired()` inside the refreshToken method.

Another example:

```
getQuestions: function() {    
    return Auth.refreshToken().then(function(){
         return $http.get(url + ver + '/questions');
    });
}

refreshToken: function() {
    if (_this.tokenIsExpired())
     return _this.getAuth(OAuth).then(function (access_obj) {
        //set token
    });
    else return $q.resolve(/*value needed?*/);
}
```

Comment: I'm wondering if instead of wrapping each `$http` request in `return Auth.refreshToken().then(function () {`, shouldn't I use `$httpProvider.interceptors` to intercept the requests before they go out, check if Auth needs to refresh the token, then it will move on to the `$http` request?

Comment: That would be the best approach. in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

This is failing because when you refresh the authToken you just call the get but don't return the promise it returns.

Try this:

```
refreshToken: function(callback) {
    ...
    _this.getAuth(OAuth).success(function (access_obj) {
        //set token
        return callback();
    })...
```

but I would not mix callbacks and promises, would instead do:

```
refreshToken: function(callback) {
    var promise = $q.defer();
    _this.getAuth(OAuth).success(function (access_obj) {
        //set token
        promise.resolve();
    })...
```

then:

```
if (Auth.tokenIsExpired()) {
    Auth.refreshToken().then(function() { return get() });
} else {
    return get();
}
```

Most preferable to clean this up would be to make the token check return a promise itself that resolves once it confirms or refreshes the token so the final would just be:

```
Auth.checkToken().then(function() { return get() });
```

Comment: I tried this, gives me `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` for `Question.getQuestions().then...`